# SFAuthenticationSession, ASWebAuthenticationSession universal links redirect urls

Tags: ios, oauth, openid-connect, sfauthenticationsession, aswebauthenticationsession

I still don't quite get it.

As far as I understand it we should do `https` redirects instead of using custom url schemes because everyone could define the custom schemes into their apps. Why are then Apple's solutions `SFAuthenticationSession(used before iOS 12)`, `ASWebAuthenticationSession` designed to use custom url schemes?

We have universal links enabled, so I thought it should be fairly easy to use a universal link. To test that I passed the https redirect to the `ASWebAuthenticationSession` and checked in the `application:continueUserActivity:restorationHandler:` callback in the app delegate for the redirect. It worked. Trying the same thing for the `SFAuthenticationSession` on iOS 11 on the other hand fails.

Am I overlooking something here? Isn't this really a security problem or am I listening at the wrong place to get the callback for the `SFAuthenticationSession`?